# How to save images for React application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, webpack, create-react-app

I have a react application (generated with`create-react-app` so with webpack) that uses a JSON file to retrieve the text content and image URL or relative path. What's the best way to save these images provided that the content in the JSON might change over time:

1. Import all images mentioned in the JSON in the project and save them in the `src` folder.
2. Save the images in other services like S3 and then quote the URL in the JSON file.
3. Save the images in the `public` folder.

Answer (score 10):

Any of these approaches will work, however, each has their own advantages and disavantages.

#### `src` folder

Images stored here have the added bonus of being able to be imported as a JavaScript module:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

Webpack will include imported files in the bundle, and images under ~10K will be converted to data URIs to avoid extra network requests. Missing files will also cause compilation errors rather than 404s, and filenames will have hashes to bust cache when the content changes.

More info:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/

#### Other services like S3

This works just like any other external server or CDN.

#### `public` folder

Files in `public` will not be bundled by Webpack, and so do not get any post-processing treatment like minification. Additionally, you will need to use the `PUBLIC_URL` environment variable. Other files in the `public` folder such as `public/index.html` would have this:

```
<img src="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.png">
```

From JavaScript code in `src`:

```
render() {
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/logo.png'} />;
}
```

The `public` folder is helpful when you need to reference images with specific file names.

More info:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: if you have 100 images to render, you are going to add 100 imports? not scalable!

Comment: @edwardtorvalds see the "public folder" option then, or S3 option